# d3 forced layout graph label and text on vertex and edges

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas, svg, graph

I am trying to create forced directed graph using d3 v4 .

I am able to create vertex and edges ,but not able to add name/text inside vertex shape .

For Edges text should be above line in its half length.

The below code is adding text but not in correct position

```
node.append("text").
attr("dx", 6).attr("dy", ".35em")
.style("font-size",10).text(function(d) { return d.name });
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sumeetpri/u3hhbkxj/5/)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a group of node and link:

1. node is group to hold the circle
2. link is group to hold the line connection

Redefine `node` to append the data:

```
node = node.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id;});
//var node pointing to group cos still node = g.append("g")
```

Then update it to append a circle:

```
node = node.enter().append("circle")
//var node now pointing to circle on group
```

Create text on the node group, not the circle. Append the text to the group and store it in a variable:

```
 uu = node.enter().append("text")
```

Then update the `x and y` position of the text the same way you update `cx and cy` of the circle:

```
function ticked() {//update x and y of uu variable}
```

```js
var createD3 = function(){
        var svg = d3.select("svg"),
            width = +svg.attr("width"),
            height = +svg.attr("height"),
            color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

            var a = {id: "a",name:"y"},
                b = {id: "b",name:"x"},
                c = {id: "c",name:"z"},
                nodes = [a, b, c],
                links = [{source: a, target: b},{source: b, target: c},{source: c, target: a}];


            var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
                .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-1000))
                .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).distance(200))
                .force("x", d3.forceX())
                .force("y", d3.forceY())
                .alphaTarget(1)
                .on("tick", ticked);



        var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")"),
            link = g.append("g").attr("stroke", "#000").attr("stroke-width", 1.5).selectAll(".link"),
            node = g.append("g").attr("stroke-width", 1.5).selectAll(".node");

        restart();

        function restart() {

          // Apply the general update pattern to the nodes.
          node = node.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id;});
          node.exit().remove();
      uu = node.enter().append("text").text(function(d) { return d.name }).attr("fill",'blue').attr('text-anchor','middle').style('font-size',24)
          node = node.enter().append("circle").attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.id); }).attr("r", 8).merge(node);
                  
        //var labels = node

          // Apply the general update pattern to the links.
          link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });
          link.exit().remove();
          link = link.enter().append("line").merge(link);

          // Update and restart the simulation.
          simulation.nodes(nodes);
          simulation.force("link").links(links);
          simulation.alpha(1).restart();
        }

        function ticked() {
          node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
              .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

            uu.attr("x", function(d,i) { 
       if(i==0){return d.x-80;}
        if(i==1){return d.x+10;}
         if(i==2){return d.x+80;}

      })
              .attr("y", function(d,i) { 
          if(i==0){return d.y+40;}
           if(i==1){return d.y-80;}
            if(i==2){return d.y+80;}

          })
          
          
          link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
              .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
              .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
              .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
        }
    };
        createD3();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="500"></svg>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154840/discussion-between-sumeet-and-kekuatan).